# ESP32/esptool.py: what can be the reason for esptool.py reporting connection problems, while connection works fine in general?

Tags: embedded, esp32, micropython, tty, espressif-idf

Maybe not a StackOverflow question, but I didn't find a better candidate in the StackExchange ecosystem..

I'm struggling with bringing new firmware to a [ESP32-S3](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-esp32-s3-feather/overview) based device using `esptool.py` (v4.7.0). The error I get is `No serial data received`:

```
$ esptool.py --chip esp32s3 --port /dev/ttyACM0 --baud 9600 erase_flash
esptool.py v4.7.0
Serial port /dev/ttyACM0
Connecting......................................

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32-S3: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
```

While flashing this device worked once, I now get the above error in 100% cases, no exceptions.

Here is what I tried:

- ☑️ access to `/dev/ttyACM0` (name, permissions)
- ☑️ check different USB-C cables / turn around cable
- ☑️ check/lower/experiment with baud rate
- ☑️ check different commands (`chip_id`, baud-rates)
- ☑️ no other processes access `/dev/ttyACM0`
- ☑️ (`rshell` which also connects to `/dev/ttyACM0` works well)
- ☑️ tried different host system
- ☑️ checked `esptool` version
- ☑️ tried pressing the `boot` / `reset` buttons before and while the the "connection" phase with different timings
- ☑️ attach / remove a battery (it's a Adafruit ESP32-S3 Feather with battery support)
- ☑️ remove anything attached to the GPIOs (nothing connected at all)
- ☑️ checked output of `dmesg` (nothing strange)
- ☑️ "inspected" output of `--trace`

.. but all without any visible effect or insights..

Strangely connecting to the very same device on the very same machine using the very same cable and connection options using `rshell` works well and a REPL can be spawned:

```
$ rshell --port /dev/ttyACM0 --baud 9600 repl                                                                                                                                                         Using buffer-size of 32
Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 (buffer-size 32)...
Trying to connect to REPL  connected
Retrieving sysname ... esp32
Testing if ubinascii.unhexlify exists ... Y
Retrieving root directories ... 
Setting time ... Feb 06, 2024 13:15:23
Evaluating board_name ... pyboard
Retrieving time epoch ... Jan 01, 2000
Entering REPL. Use Control-X to exit.
>
MicroPython v1.22.1 on 2024-01-05; Generic ESP32S3 module with ESP32S3
Type "help()" for more information.
>>>
```

Before I give up and throw away the little device, is there something else I could try?

---

Output of `--trace`

```
$ esptool.py --trace --chip esp32 --port /dev/ttyACM0 --baud 9600 erase_flash
esptool.py v4.7.0
Serial port /dev/ttyACM0
Connecting...TRACE +0.000 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.000 Write 46 bytes: 
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.101 No serial data received.
.TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.000 Write 46 bytes: 
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.101 No serial data received.
.TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=

...
... (repeated output)
... 

TRACE +0.101 No serial data received.
.

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
```

Comment: Are you successful with other, non-flash related esptool operations, like chip_id or flash_id? Example: `py.exe -m esptool --chip auto --port COM9 chip_id` (Sorry, it's a Windows OS example.) I am also using esptool 4.7.0 (though Windows) and an ESP32-S3 (Espressif, not Adafruit) and chip_id is successful for me. Also, my S3 has two USB connectors. I am plugged into the one labeled UART.